# Run a button method/function from menustrip c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've searched stack overflow, google, youtube and the book and for some reason can't find this simple answer...

All I found was how to change a font or a color, which I already know, but not how to run a button method/function using the menustrip.

For example, if I click on the "Calculate" option in the menustrip - it will run my button on my form called "Calculate".

I've tried:

```
this.btnCalculate();
```

and that obviously doesn't work, maybe I have to use the "using" function?

I'm lost, can someone help please?

```
private void calculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnCalculate();
    }
```

If I'm not making any sense...
Implement the Calculate, and Clear Form menu options by calling the existing command button methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options.

**Option 1:**

Move your logic inside `btnCalculate_Click` to another function, and call this method in both `btnClick` and `menustripClick` events.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ExecuteLogic();
}

private void calculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
   ExecuteLogic();
}

void ExecuteLogic()
{
    // logic goes here.  
}
```

**Option 2:**

Not preferred choice, but works.

```
private void calculateToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.btnCalculate_Click(sender, e); 

    //You also can use:
    //this.btnCalculate.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: When I use option two it says "Non invocable member...cannot be used like a method".
I tried method 1 but now I'm getting a bunch of errors for all the other "voids" from other buttons - Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or strut.

Comment: In option 2 you can use `this.btnCalculate.PerformClick()`. Also it's better to pass `this.btnCalculate` as sender.

Comment: Ahh yes thank you that works!
this.btnCalculate.PerformClick()